# Make my counter score save highest score even after app closes

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, scripting

So I am making a rocket app, still early into development. I wrote code that counts a score when I collide with objects. How to make it so it saves my highest score and can display it? As soon as I leave my scene it sets the score back to 0 :( please help thank you!

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class POINTS1 : MonoBehaviour
{

public Text countText;
public Text winText;


private Rigidbody rb;
private int count;

void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    count = 0;
    SetCountText();
    winText.text = "";
}


void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Pickup"))
    {
        other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        count = count + 100;
        SetCountText();
    }
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("minus300"))
    {
        other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        count = count -300;
        SetCountText();
    }
}

void SetCountText()
{
        countText.text = "Score: " + count.ToString();
        if (count >= 5000)
        {
            winText.text = "Good Job!";
        }
    }



}
```

EDIT: So I tried the code you kindly provided, am I doing something wrong? It doesn't work... I think we might need a GUI element to display the highest score.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class POINTS1 : MonoBehaviour
{

public Text countText;
public Text winText;


private Rigidbody rb;
private int count;


void Start()
{
rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
count = 0;
SetCountText();
winText.text = "";
}



void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Pickup"))
{
    other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    count = count + 100;
    SetCountText();
}
if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("minus300"))
{
    other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    count = count -300;
    SetCountText();

}
}

void SetCountText()
{
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score", count);
PlayerPrefs.Save();
count = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score", 0);
countText.text = "Score: " + count.ToString();
    if (count >= 5000)
    {
        winText.text = "Good Job!";
    }
}


}
//PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score", count);  
//PlayerPrefs.Save();
//count = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score", 0);
```

Comment: You would have to save the score somewhere (e.g. database, xml, text, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the idea! How would I save the score somewhere? Sorry I'm not fully educated in scripting in c# or js, I'm a bit past the basics :/

Comment: Making a simple text file would be the easiest. Check out these two classes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: What GameObject is your POINTS1 Monobehaviour attached to? Have you tried printing the value of count to the console? The code looks fine, and should work.

Comment: It is attached to my Player and to the count text and win text elements. And how do I "Print value of count to console"?

Answer (score 2):

What you want is the [PlayerPrefs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) class. PlayerPrefs allows you to store data between sessions of your game.

You can save data by calling **PlayerPrefs.Set** for any supported data type (int, float or string), and get it by using the corresponding **PlayerPrefs.Get**.

For example, if you want to save the score, you can do it like so.

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score", count);  
PlayerPrefs.Save();
```

And get it back by

```
count = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score", 0);
```

Comment: That looks just like what I need. Please look at the extra details I provided in the answer below.

Comment: Never post another question as an answer. Edit your original post and update it. Please remember that others may find this thread in the future, and you should allow for them to get answers as well

Comment: Very sorry, I corrected that and updated my 1st post. Please find the new info in the 1st post. Thanks!